# swift properties setter not getting called

Tags: swift

I have tried to calculate the area of a triangle using getter and setter with the help of formula area = (length * base)/2 using getter and setter

```
    class Triangle {
   var length: Double
   var base:Double 
   var name:String 
     init(length: Double, base:Double, name:String ) {

    self.length = length
    self.name =  name
    self.base = base  
    }

    var area: Double {
    get { // getter
        return base * length
    }
         set { //setter
             area = newValue / 2.0
    }
   }
  }


 var triangle = Triangle(length:5,base:4,name:"f")
 print(triangle.area)
```

The area returned should be 10 but it returns 20 i.e. the setter step is not getting called. The compiler is ignoring the setter step i.e. even if I comment-out the setter step, it makes no difference to the compiler. I want to use setter, how to go about it ?

Comment: You are not setting `area` so why should the setter be called?

Comment: Caution: If you ever call the setter you will run into an infinite loop --> crash.

Comment: @vadian Not only an infinite loop, but an actual **Stack Overflow**!

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, indeed 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like area is a computed property. Shouldn't it be a read-only computed property? Seems to me that there are multiple triangles with a given area but different height/base values, so you **can't** set the area in a meaningful way.

```
var area: Double {
  get { // getter
    return 0.5 * base * length
  }
}
```

You are also missing the `/2` part of the area formula `a = 1/2 b * h`. That's why your result is 20 when it should be 10.

Comment: I had done the above, I just wanted to know the function of setter.

Answer (score 0):

`area` is a computed variable. It doesn't store any value. So you have to save your newValue somewhere. E.g.,

```
class Triangle {
    var length: Double
    var base:Double
    var name:String
    init(length: Double, base:Double, name:String ) {
        self.length = length
        self.name =  name
        self.base = base
    }

    var area: Double {
        get { // getter
            return base * length
        }
        set { //setter
            let tmpArea = newValue / 2.0
            let squared = sqrt(tmpArea)
            base = squared
            length = squared
        }
    } }
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have a setter at all, since there are an infinite number of triangles with the same area and different base/height values. Seems to me that area should be a read-only computed property.

Comment: @DuncanC probably yes. It really depends on what he/she wants

Comment: @Vyacheslav -  It shows error with "sqrt" as I am using  swift sandbox. What is the use of "sqrt" function and why so many assignment of values.